# Degree of a field over a fixed subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

My problem is the following:

> Let $K, L$ be fields and $u_1,\cdots, u_n$ be $n$ distinct field homomorphisms $K\to L$, define $E:=\{a\in K: u_1(a)=\cdots=u_n(a)\}$. Then $[K:E]\geqslant n$.

One can view $K$ as a subfield of $L$ via $u_1$ and assume $u_1={\rm id}$ and by considering normal closure of the image of the $u_i$'s inside an algebraic closure of $L$, one can assume the extension $L/K$ is normal, and each $u_i$ extends to an automomorphism $v_i$ of $L$. I want to use the group $H$ generated by the $v_i$'s (so $E=K\cap L^H$) and apply Artin’s lemma saying that if $H$ is finite, then $L/L^H$ is a finite Galois extension with group $H$. But I'm afraid $H$ can be in finite. Any ideas?

Comment: How does $L$ enter (in the first 2 lines)?

Comment: Since you claim you can view $K$ as a subfield of $L$, I'm guessing the $u_i$ are distinct field homomorphisms $u_i: K\to L$ (and are hence injective).

Comment: @Liam Of course, field homomorphisms are injective. Sorry I forget to say about the source and target.

Comment: If $K/E$ is not algebraic then we are done. Thus we assume it is algebraic, 

$F=\prod_j u_j(K)$ is algebraic over $E$ and

$K$ has $n$-distinct $E$-embeddings into $\overline{F}$. If $K/E$ has finite degree then it is a tower of simple extensions, $[K:E]$ is the product of the degrees of the minimal polynomials, which gives that $K$ has at most $[K:E]$ distinct embeddings.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for pointing out this, this is cool, only using a description of separable degree of $K/E$!